How to find the $\zeta$ representation of a $L$-series
Consider the following problem:
Show that for $s>1$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}.$$
($\mu$ denotes the Mobius function)
My approach:
One may first note that the series converges for $s>1$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$ converges for $s_0=1$ thus it converges for $Re(s)>Re(s_0) $.
Now since
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$$ we can write $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}}$$ thus we get
$$\tag{1}\bigl( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} \bigr) \bigl( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \bigr)=1$$
Let $\epsilon(n):=1 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\eta(n):=1$ for $n=1$ and $0$ for $n \geq 2$.
For the Dirichlet Convolution $\ast$ and two arithmetic functions $a,b$ we know the following formula:
$$\bigl( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a(n)}{n^s} \bigr) \bigl( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b(n)}{n^s} \bigr)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(a \ast b)(n)}{n^s}$$
Note that we can rewrite $(1)$ as $$\bigl( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon(n)}{n^s} \bigr) \bigl( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \bigr)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\eta(n)}{n^s}.$$
Since $\epsilon \ast \mu = \eta$ we are already done.
My first question is, if this solution is correct.
I am interested in this kind of problem. Doing this specific problem, it was not that difficult since the only thing I needed to do is to write $\zeta(s)$ as a series and use the property of the Dirichlet-Convolution. Then the only thing left is to show the convolution identity. But what if only the left hand side is given and one has to find the right hand side/representation by $\zeta$?
For example, let $\tau(n):=\sum_{d |n} 1$, $\Lambda$ denote the von Mangoldt function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function) how would one solve an exercise of the form:
Represent the series through the $\zeta$ function for
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}
,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tau(n)}{n^s}
,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu^2(n)}{n^s}$$
and so on...
How would one approach this kind of problem?

Another profitable way to think about these problems is via the Euler product, assuming the coefficients of the Dirichlet series are multiplicative. In the example you gave, we have
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p} \left(1 - p^{-s}\right) = \left(\prod_{p} 1/\left(1 - p^{-s}\right)\right)^{-1} = \zeta(s)^{-1}$$
since the Möbius function is multiplicative and takes value $-1$ for any prime $p$.
The von Mangoldt function is not multiplicative, so more slightly more trickery is required in this particular case. A starting point is to compute $\log \zeta(s)$ (again do this via the Euler product).

Yes, your approach is correct. However you can make things more clear by directly using the relation between the Dirichlet convolution and Dirichlet series that you presented.
I will assume that you know how to write some classical arithmetical functions as a Dirichlet convolution. In your example, we have that
$
(\mu\ast 1)(n)=\delta_1(n),
$
where $1(n)=1,\forall n$ and $\delta_1(n)$ is the identity, i.e., it is $1$ if $n=1$ and $0$ if $n>1$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}\zeta(s)&=\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}\sum_{n≥1}\frac{1}{n^s}\\
&=\sum_{n≥1}\frac{(\mu\ast 1)(n)}{n^s}\\
&=\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\delta_1(n)}{n^s}\\
&=1,
\end{align*}
for $\Re(s)>1$.
We take the same approach for the other functions. Note that the divisor function is $\tau(n)=\sum_{d|n}1=(1\ast 1)(n)$, so we have
$
\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\tau(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n≥1}\frac{1}{n^s}\sum_{n≥1}\frac{1}{n^s}=\zeta(s)^2,
$
for $\Re(s)>1$.
The Von Mangoldt function needs more care but we have a few ways to do it. One is to note that $\Lambda(n)=(\mu\ast\log(\cdot))(n)$ and by termwise differentiation,
$
\zeta'(s)=-\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\log(n)}{n^s},
$
$\Re(s)>1$. Then,
$
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}:=\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s)=-\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s},
$
for $\Re(s)>1$. Another (more common) way is to calculate the logarithmic derivative of the Euler product of the Riemann zeta function, as commented CJ Dowd.
For the last one, I think it is much easier using the Euler product formula. We have that $\mu^2$ works as an indicator of the square free numbers, so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n≥1}\frac{\mu^2(n)}{n^s}&=\prod_p (1+\mu^2(p)p^{-s}+\mu^2(p^2)p^{-2s}+\cdots)\\
&=\prod_p (1+p^{-s})\\
&=\prod_p (1+p^{-s})\frac{(1-p^{-s})}{(1-p^{-s})}\\
&=\prod_p\frac{(1-p^{-2s})}{(1-p^{-s})}\\
&=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)},
\end{align*}
for $\Re(s)>1$. And as a consequence of this last result we have that, if $f(n)=\mu(d)$ if $n=d^2$ and $0$ otherwise (that is, if $n$ is a perfect square),
$
\mu^2(n)=(1 \ast f)(n)=\sum_{d^2|n}\mu(d),
$
which is a known result and if you already knew and proved it in another way, you could use it directly instead of using the Euler product formula.
